# numpy sum antidiagonals of array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy

Given a numpy ndarray, I would like to take the first two axes, and replace them with a new axis, which is the sum of their antidiagonals.

In particular, suppose I have variables x,y,z,..., and the entries of my array represent the probability

```
array[i,j,k,...] = P(x=i, y=j, z=k, ...)
```

I would like to obtain

```
new_array[l,k,...] = P(x+y=l, z=k, ...) = sum_i P(x=i, y=l-i, z=k, ...)
```

i.e., `new_array[l,k,...]` is the sum of all `array[i,j,k,...]` such that `i+j=l`.

What is the most efficient and/or cleanest way to do this in numpy?

EDIT to add:
On recommendation of @hpaulj, here is the obvious iterative solution:

```
array = numpy.arange(30).reshape((2,3,5))
array = array / float(array.sum()) # make it a probability
new_array = numpy.zeros([array.shape[0] + array.shape[1] - 1] + list(array.shape[2:]))
for i in range(array.shape[0]):
    for j in range(array.shape[1]):
        new_array[i+j,...] += array[i,j,...]
new_array.sum() # == 1
```

Comment: Give us the obvious iterative solution.  It's easier to suggest improvements where there's a working example to test against.

Comment: The cleanest is to define `P(x,y,z)`, and a `P1(l,z,fn)`.  The second takes care of iterating over possible `x`,`y` values and applying them to your `fn=P`.  `P1` can't be vectorized (made more efficient) unless `P` itself is vectorized.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a `trace` function that gives the sum of a diagonal.  You can specify the offset and 2 axes (0 and 1 are the defaults).  And to get the antidiagonal, you just need to flip one dimension.  `np.flipud` does that, though it's just `[::-1,...]` indexing.

Putting those together,

```
np.array([np.trace(np.flipud(array),offset=k) for k in range(-1,3)])
```

matches your `new_array`.

It still loops over the possible values of `l` (4 in this case).  `trace` itself is compiled.

In this small case, it's actually slower than your double loop (2x3 steps).  Even if I move the `flipud` out of the inner loop, it is still slower.  I don't know how this scales for larger arrays.

Part of the problem with vectorizing this even further is that fact that each diagonal has a different length.

```
In [331]: %%timeit
array1 = array[::-1]
np.array([np.trace(array1,offset=k) for k in range(-1,3)])
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 87.4 µs per loop

In [332]: %%timeit 
new_array = np.zeros([array.shape[0] + array.shape[1] - 1] + list(array.shape[2:]))                                                       
for i in range(2):
    for j in range(3):
        new_array[i+j] += array[i,j]
   .....: 
10000 loops, best of 3: 43.5 µs per loop
```

`scipy.sparse` has a `dia` format, which stores the values of nonzero diagonals.  It stores a padded array of values, along with the offsets.

```
array([[12,  0,  0,  0],
       [ 8, 13,  0,  0],
       [ 4,  9, 14,  0],
       [ 0,  5, 10, 15],
       [ 0,  1,  6, 11],
       [ 0,  0,  2,  7],
       [ 0,  0,  0,  3]])
array([-3, -2, -1,  0,  1,  2,  3])
```

While that's a way of getting around the issue of variable diagonal lengths, I don't think it helps in this case where you just need their sums.

Comment: Thanks, was not aware of the flipud function -- seems like flipud + trace should be faster for large arrays because it at least removes one of the loops.